# Hausdorff dimension of a dense orbit in the Lorenz attractor

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, chaos-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

If I am not mistaken, then:

- the Lorenz attractor $\mathcal{A}$ has Hausdorff dimension $\dim_H(\mathcal{A}) > 2$, and
- the Lorenz attractor $\mathcal{A}$ contains a dense orbit $\mathcal{O}$, i.e. such that $\bar{\mathcal{O}} = \mathcal{A}$.

But:

- the Hausdorff dimension does not satisfy $\dim_H(X) = \dim_H(\bar{X})$ in general,
- for example $\dim_H([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ while $\dim_H([0,1]) = 1$.

What is the Hausdorff dimension of a dense orbit in the Lorenz attractor? Is it $\dim_H(\mathcal{A})$, or smaller?

Comment: Any single orbit of the Lorenz system is a smooth curve and, therefore, has Hausdorff dimension $1$. I think this is crystal clear for a curve defined over $[0,N]$ for any $N\in\mathbb N$. To extend the result a curve defined over $[0,\infty)$, simply take a countable union of intervals as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks, I just realized the same. I would accept your answer, but it's written in a comment.

Comment: See also [Hausdorff dimension of Hamiltonian orbit closure and symplectic leaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322507/hausdorff-dimension-of-hamiltonian-orbit-closure-and-symplectic-leaves)