# How big can the Hausdorff dimension of the closure of a smooth curve be?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, curves, dimension-theory-analysis

Consider curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Smooth curves have Hausdorff dimension $1$.

The closure of a smooth curve can have Hausdorff dimension $> 1$.
(For example, a curve dense in a torus.)

How big can the Hausdorff dimension of the closure of a smooth curve be?

(Can it be $> 2$? For instance, can there be a smooth curve dense in a solid torus?)

Comment: How are you defining a smooth curve?  Does it just have to be a smooth mapping $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, or must it be regular as well ($\gamma' \neq 0$)?  See my comment on [Vasily Mitch's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325329/248639) below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can extend the example you mention, sometimes called an [irrational winding of a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus#Irrational_winding_of_a_torus), to higher-dimensional tori $\Bbb T_n$:

Pick a constants $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \Bbb R$ such that $1, \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, and denote $$\alpha := (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) \in \Bbb R^n .$$ Then, the image of the curve $$\gamma : \Bbb R \to \Bbb T_n \cong \Bbb R^n / \Bbb Z^n, \qquad\gamma(t) := t \alpha \pmod {\Bbb Z^n}$$
is dense in $\Bbb T_n$.

(For $n = 2$ the linear independence condition is just that the ratio $\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$ is irrational.)

Comment: Thanks! You might also like: [Hausdorff dimension of Hamiltonian orbit closure and symplectic leaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322507/hausdorff-dimension-of-hamiltonian-orbit-closure-and-symplectic-leaves)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. I looked at your other question, but I'm too rusty on my symplectic geometry to answer it without doing some review. But it's a good question, so with luck it will get the attention of someone who can.

Comment: How to prove the image of $\gamma$ is dense in $\Bbb T^n$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210717/an-irrational-flow-on-a-torus-is-dense for the $n = 2$ case. The general case is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Consider all points in $[0,1]^n$ with rational coordinates. We can enumerate them with natural numbers, so they produce a sequence $P_i$. We can also enumerate them in such a way so $|P_{i+1}-P_i|>\epsilon$ for every $i$ and fixed $\epsilon$. Now you can assign a spline that goes through all points in a succession. By construction, the closure of the curve will include $[0,1]^n$ and thus will have the dimension $n$

Comment: It is not at all clear to me that a spline through countably many point is smooth (or even differentiable, for that matter).  Could you expand on that point, please?

Comment: Spline is a piecewise function with matching $k$-derivatives at nodes. So the curve between nodes $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$ doesn't depend on the position of other points.

Comment: If the curve only needs to be smooth (and not regular), then you could also just use a "smooth step function" (a function $f:[a,b] \to [0,1]$ for which $f(a) = 0$, $f(b) = 1$, and all the derivatives vanish at either end) to travel along the straight-line segments between each pair of successive points.